# Using the new SaaS Table Adapter in an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Azure recently released a SaaS Table adapter for Azure functions. I know this feature is experimental with no documentation, but I'm trying to see if anyone has this working.

My bindings (function.json):

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "somePathToBlob",
      "connection": "connectionName_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubTable",
      "name": "output",
      "connection": "sql_SQL",
      "direction": "out",
      "tableName": "tblEventStage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Then in run.csx I have:

```
public static void Run(string data, ITable<EventRecord> output, TraceWriter log)
{
    // add some records to the table
}
```

The function compiles successfully and then pops an alert message:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessAppInsights'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub: The attribute ApiHubTableAttribute indicates a table binding. The parameter type must be one of the following: Microsoft.Azure.ApiHub.ITable, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IAsyncCollector. To bind to a table client do not specify a table name. To bind to an entity specify the entity identifier.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution - I was using System.Data.Linq ITable instead of ITable from Microsoft.Azure.ApiHub.  I removed System.Data.Linq and added nuget package Microsoft Azure ApiHub SDK.  This requires adding a file package.json:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.ApiHub.Sdk": "0.6.10-alpha"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Records can be inserted to the table using:

```
output.CreateEntityAsync(record);
```